# Filter messages sent to a particular domain, and only that domain

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a set of filters that auto add emails sent within a particular domain as 'internal'

e.g. if me@example.com sends an email to boss@example.com, it is tagged internal

The problem is, my filter is not truely internal, because say I send an email to person@example2.com and CC boss@example.com, it picks the latter up and flags it internal, but this is not an internal email.

I need to filter emails sent to a particular domain, and **only** that domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting my comment to an answer, as requested.)

I'm afraid that Gmail's filters aren't sophisticated enough for that.

Answer (score 2):

The `To:` filter appears to pick up cc: as well (and bcc:?). In the advanced search the `to:` operator does the same (which is user friendly to the masses, but not so helpful when you want more control), but there is also a `cc:` operator. You seem to be able to use this in the search filter as well. eg:

> `To:` @example.com -cc:@example.com

Which appears to create a filter of the form... `to:(@example.com -cc:@example.com)`. Although the syntax looks a bit wrong, it does appear to filter all the emails that contain an @example.com address in the `to:` field but not in the `cc:` field.

However, this is not really a solution since it excludes emails that are sent to @example.com in both the `to:` and `cc:` fields. But may be something to work with?

**EDIT:**

You can perhaps combine the condition when the address appears in both the `to:` and `cc:` fields by using/appending something like:

> ... OR (to:@example.com cc:@example.com)

Although I'm not sure if this can be successfully combined with the above rule?

Comment: experiments adding -cc did and its variants did not meet with success. It then leads tot he problem of "I want it to flag mails CC'ed to example.com and ONLY example.com", it also removed some legitimate internal emails from the filter ( false negatives ), and brought in emails that were sent itnernally but CC'ed external people ( false positives )

Comment: Keep in mind that when adding a filter, one can't just have the query as a single string in a textbox, the to and from fields etc are separate boxes